# Query for Filling Gaps and Fix Overlapping Date Ranges in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

How to Query for: Filling Gaps and Fix Overlapping Date Ranges in Oracle SQL

```sql
CREATE TABLE PROD_TABLE(Assignment_ID   number, Effective_START_Date date,  Effective_END_Date date, DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(100));
INSERT INTO PROD_TABLE VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('1/1/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('2/1/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DEPT1');
INSERT INTO PROD_TABLE VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('2/2/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('2/2/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DEPT1');
INSERT INTO PROD_TABLE VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('2/3/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('3/19/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DEPT1');
INSERT INTO PROD_TABLE VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('3/20/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('12/31/4712', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DEPT1');

CREATE TABLE STAGING_TABLE(Assignment_ID    number, Effective_START_Date date,  Effective_END_Date date, DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(100));
INSERT INTO STAGING_TABLE VALUES (30001,    TO_DATE('2/2/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('5/4/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DEPT1');
INSERT INTO STAGING_TABLE VALUES (30001,    TO_DATE('5/5/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('2/2/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DEPT1');
```

In the STAGING_TABLE there are two records
that overlaps the record in the PROD_TABLE.
STAGING RECORDS:
1.
start date: 2/2/2020
end date: 5/4/2020

2.
start date: 5/5/2020
end date: 2/2/2021

PROD_TABLE:
The records above overlaps the records
1.
start date: 2/2/2020
end date: 2/2/2021

So want to merge the STAGING_TABLE records into the PROD_TABLE records. After merging, the expected records should be
1.
start date: 2/2/2020
end date: 5/4/2020
2.
start date: 5/5/2020
end date: 2/2/2021

This is the query I've created so far. Is there any simple approach to do this?

```sql
WITH query1 AS ( SELECT prod_table.Assignment_ID,
       GREATEST(staging_table.effective_start_date, prod_table.effective_start_date) AS effective_START_date,
       LEAST(staging_table.effective_end_date, prod_table.effective_end_date) AS effective_END_date,
       staging_table.DEPARTMENT   FROM PROD_TABLE prod_table,
       STAGING_TABLE staging_table  WHERE prod_table.Assignment_ID = staging_table.Assignment_ID    AND prod_table.effective_start_date <
staging_table.effective_end_date    AND prod_table.effective_end_date
> staging_table.effective_start_date )     SELECT * FROM query1 UNION SELECT prod_table.Assignment_ID,
       prod_table.effective_start_date,
       prod_table.effective_end_date,
       prod_table.DEPARTMENT   FROM PROD_TABLE prod_table  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM query1 qry
                    WHERE prod_table.Assignment_ID = qry.Assignment_ID
                      AND prod_table.effective_start_date BETWEEN qry.effective_start_date AND qry.effective_end_date) ORDER BY  1, 2;
```

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what logic you are applying to get that expected output and what the logic would be for different inputs (that do not cover an entire range from `prod_table`). Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: an English explanation of the problem you are trying to solve and the logic that needs to be implemented; and the expected output as text (not images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the rows in `PROD_TABLE` that fully contain rows in `STAGING_TABLE` then you can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO prod_table dst
USING (
  SELECT p.ROWID AS rid,
         s.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ROWID ORDER BY s.effective_start_date) AS rn
  FROM   prod_table p
         INNER JOIN staging_table s
         ON     p.assignment_id        =  s.assignment_id
            AND p.effective_start_date <= s.effective_start_date
            AND s.effective_end_date   <= p.effective_end_date
            AND p.department           = s.department
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid AND src.rn = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET    effective_start_date = src.effective_start_date,
         effective_end_date   = src.effective_end_date
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (assignment_id, effective_start_date, effective_end_date, department)
  VALUES (src.assignment_id, src.effective_start_date, src.effective_end_date, src.department);
```

Which, for the sample data, then after the `MERGE` then `prod_table` contains:

| ASSIGNMENT_ID | EFFECTIVE_START_DATE | EFFECTIVE_END_DATE | DEPARTMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30001 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | DEPT1 |
| 30001 | 2020-02-02 00:00:00 | 2020-05-04 00:00:00 | DEPT1 |
| 30001 | 2021-02-03 00:00:00 | 2021-03-19 00:00:00 | DEPT1 |
| 30001 | 2023-03-20 00:00:00 | 4712-12-31 00:00:00 | DEPT1 |
| 30001 | 2020-05-05 00:00:00 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00 | DEPT1 |

---

#### Update:

If you want to `SELECT` (and not `MERGE`) the all the data from the `staging_table` and the data from the `prod_table` that does not completely enclose a row from the `staging_table` then use `UNION ALL` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   prod_table p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM staging_table s
                   WHERE p.assignment_id        =  s.assignment_id
                   AND   p.effective_start_date <= s.effective_start_date
                   AND   s.effective_end_date   <= p.effective_end_date
                   AND   p.department           = s.department)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   staging_table;
```

Which outputs:

| ASSIGNMENT_ID | EFFECTIVE_START_DATE | EFFECTIVE_END_DATE | DEPARTMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30001 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | DEPT1 |
| 30001 | 2021-02-03 00:00:00 | 2021-03-19 00:00:00 | DEPT1 |
| 30001 | 2023-03-20 00:00:00 | 4712-12-31 00:00:00 | DEPT1 |
| 30001 | 2020-02-02 00:00:00 | 2020-05-04 00:00:00 | DEPT1 |
| 30001 | 2020-05-05 00:00:00 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00 | DEPT1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YAnCHMfe)

Comment: @MTO - THANK YOU SO MUCH for answering my question. The SQL will be used for reporting. I have no insert access to PROD_TABLE.

Comment: @MTO - AGAIN, THANK YOU SO MUCH. APPRECIATE yourHUGE HELP on this!